# C# Modularised Conversion utility program mimic of google search when converting measurements

Tags: c#

The task that i have is to create a replica of a search engine that converts measurements. The user enters "4cm to inches" and the program makes the appropriate calculations to give the answer in inches. Now this program must be able to convert through a range of different measurements and dimensions eg Volume and area also. So far i have been able to make it convert strictly from cm to inches using properties of strings ie Substring, IndexOf, Convert.Toint16 and i want it to continue doing so but i'm struggling modularising it so that it can do a range of different calculations efficiently. This is what i have so far...

```
        Toconvert = Console.ReadLine();

        Cmpos = Toconvert.IndexOf("cm");
        Inchespos = Toconvert.IndexOf("inches"); 
        CmUnits = Toconvert.Substring(Cmpos, 2);
        InchesUnits = Toconvert.Substring(Inchespos, 6);
        number2convert = Convert.ToInt16(Toconvert.Substring(0, Cmpos));
        Inches = number2convert / 2.54;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1} is {2:F2} {3}", number2convert, CmUnits, Inches, InchesUnits);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

This is very problematic/limiting and has me perplexed. Every route ive taken ive encountered an error of some sort.

All i want it to do is read whats been input by the user, and outputs the appropriate value from what the computer has.

Comment: A hint: String.Split and/or Regex.Split can break up your input into `["4","cm","to","inches"]` (without you needing to hardcode "cm" or "inches")

Comment: @Blorgbeard doesn't work because can't implicitly convert type char to string. Tried Convert.ToString and casting with no success

Answer (score 0):

Learn Regex, it will be your friend, especially for something like this.

Here's a query that will help for your particular case:

`([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*)[\s]*([\w]+)[\s]+[\w]+[\s]+([\w]+)`

Loosely translated: Look for numbers (4), then a space or not, then a word (cm), then space, then a word (to), then space, then a word (inches).

Regex offers "groups" (the items in parentheses). for `4cm to inches` in the above Regex, the groups are `4`, `cm` and `inches`...all the useful bits.

[This is an example of it in use](https://regexr.com/44ike).  There's also very good explanations for each step of the Regex (Click on the "Explain" tab).

Here's a C# example:

```
  var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*)[\s]*([\w]+)[\s]+[\w]+[\s]+([\w]+)");
  var match = reg.Match("4cm to inches");

  double numberToConvert = double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
  string fromUnits = match.Groups[2].Value;
  string toUnits = match.Groups[3].Value;
```